# React canvas drawing new line removes existing line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm working on a hangman game in React where I'm encountering a problem when drawing to the canvas. The lines get drawn, however the previous line is not shown i.e. the first line is drawn when user guesses wrong for the first time. Then if the user has another wrong guess instead of the two lines combining and making the sort of "L" shape the first line disappears.

Here is a minimal demo (word to guess (or in this case not to guess) is word): https://codesandbox.io/s/hangman-demo-2of1jy?file=/src/App.jsx

App.jsx:

```
const draw = (ctx) => {
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#F2F2F0";
    ctx.beginPath();

    switch (guessesLeft) {
      case 9:
        ctx.moveTo(ctx.canvas.width / 2 - 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
        ctx.lineTo(ctx.canvas.width / 2 + 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
        break;

      case 8:
        ctx.moveTo(ctx.canvas.width / 2 - 200, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
        ctx.lineTo(ctx.canvas.width / 2 - 200, 50);

        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    ctx.stroke();
  };
```

Then in the App.jsx return:

```
  return  <Canvas draw={draw} />
```

Canvas.jsx:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const Canvas = ({ draw }) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvasRef.current.width = canvasRef.current.offsetWidth;
    canvasRef.current.height = canvasRef.current.offsetHeight;

    draw(context);
  }, [draw]);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} id="game" />;
};
export default Canvas;
```

I have tried wrapping the entire Canvas function in React.memo and I have tried wrapping the draw function from App in a useCallback. I have tried doing both at the same time, and also tried doing one at a time.

I'm not really familiar with canvas, so I have also tried deleting ctx.beginPath(), and calling it in each of the two switch cases. I have also tried moving ctx.stroke() around and calling it in each case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but if anyone has a better one I'm all ears.

So the problem, I believe is that I'm using a switch case and breaking for each case. So the current solution is to add the previous lines drawn for each case.

Don't really like it. Hope someone has a better idea.

Something like this:

```
switch (guessesLeft) {
      case 9:

        ctx.moveTo((ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
        ctx.lineTo((ctx.canvas.width / 2) + 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
        break;

      case 8:

        // first line
        ctx.moveTo((ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
        ctx.lineTo((ctx.canvas.width / 2) + 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50);

        // second line
        ctx.moveTo((ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 200, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
        ctx.lineTo((ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 200, 50);

        break;

    }

    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

EDIT: Found what I believe is a better solution.

First I created a new JS file with all the different draw functionality, like this:

```
const draw = (startX, startY, endX, endY) => {

    const canvas = document.querySelector("#game");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#F2F2F0";

    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.stroke();

}

const bottomGallow = (ctx) => {
    draw((ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50, (ctx.canvas.width / 2) + 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
}

const upwardsGallow = (ctx) => {
    draw((ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50, (ctx.canvas.width / 2) + 250, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
    draw((ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 230, ctx.canvas.height - 50, (ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 230, 50);
}

const topGallow = (ctx) => {
    draw((ctx.canvas.width / 2) - 232, 50, (ctx.canvas.width / 2) + 100, 50);
}

const diagonalGallow = ctx => {

}

const rope = ctx => {

}

const head = (ctx) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(60, 25, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
}

const torso = ctx => {

}

const rightArm = ctx => {

}

const leftArm = ctx => {

}

const rightLeg = ctx => {

}

const leftLeg = ctx => {
    
}


const drawArray = [leftLeg, rightLeg, leftArm, rightArm,torso,head,rope,diagonalGallow,topGallow, upwardsGallow, bottomGallow];

export {drawArray,leftLeg, rightLeg, leftArm, rightArm,torso,head,rope, diagonalGallow, bottomGallow, upwardsGallow, topGallow};
```

Then I imported the draw functions from before mentioned JS file in App.jsx, removed the switch case and did this instead:

```
    const draw = () => {
      drawArray[guessesLeft](canvasRef.current.getContext('2d'));
  }
```

Then calling this draw function when a life is deducted.

Then in Canvas.jsx I removed the draw call from useEffect and removed the draw function from the dependency array.